# mod_rpaf with apache error_log

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rpaf

I'm using mod-rpaf with Apache 2.4 and it's working properly (showing the real client IP's) in my Apache access_log... but not in my error_log. My error log just shows the client IP address of the proxy server (my load balancer in this case)

Here's an example of what I see in my error_log where 123.123.123.123 is the IP of my load balancer/proxy.

> ==> /usr/local/apache2/logs/error_log <== [Tue Jun 05 20:24:31.027525 2012] [access_compat:error] [pid 9145:tid 140485731845888] [client
>   **123.123.123.123**:20396] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /wwwroot/private/secret.pdf

The exact same request produces the following in my `access_log` where 456.456.456.456 is a real client IP (not the IP of the load balancer).

```
456.456.456.456 - - [05/Jun/2012:20:24:31 +0000] "GET /wwwroot/private/secret.pdf HTTP/1.1" 403 228 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"
```

Here's my httpd.conf entry:

```
# RPAF
LoadModule rpaf_module  modules/mod_rpaf-2.0.so
RPAFenable On
RPAFproxy_ips 127.0.0.1 123.123.123.123
RPAFsethostname On
RPAFheader X-Forwarded-For
```

What do I need to do to get the real IP addresses showing in my Apache error_log?

Comment: Are you *sure* those two logs are representing the same request?  The timestamps are nearly five minutes apart, not to mention the URI and paths don't match.

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching that -  that was only a mistake in my copy/pasting of the example - I will correct the OP. But yeah - I've tested a couple more times to verify that it's showing the same request with different IPs. (The OP is now corrected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that error log format looked strange and I didn't think there was any way to change it in 2.2 so I checked out [the docs for 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlogformat).

It seems there is now an `ErrorLogFormat` directive and your error log is in the default format, which has been updated and significantly improved since 2.2.

Apache 2.4 now includes [mod_remoteip](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_remoteip.html) which deprecates mod_rpaf.  I suspect mod_rpaf has not been updated to work with Apache 2.4 and the ErrorLogFormat directive.  The most recent version on [the download page](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/download/) is from 2008.

You should use mod_remoteip instead of mod_rpaf with Apache 2.4.

Comment: Perfect! I loaded up `mod_remoteip` and I'm in business!

Initially after loading the module, the error_log was recording the real IP and the access_log was recording the proxy's IP (the opposite of my initial problem), but to fix that I just changed the default `LogFormat` directive to use the %a formatting string instead of the %h string -- and that set everything straight. 

So to summarize, 1) Uncomment the LoadModule line for mod_remoteip 2) Change the `LogFormat %h...` directive to be `LogFormat %a...` That's all there was to it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

mod-rpaf requires just a minor change to the source to make it work with apache 2.4 which I found here
http://vova-zms.blogspot.com/2012/07/install-modrpaf-with-apache-24.html

simply replace  `remote_` with `client_` in `mod_rpaf-2.0.c`

also http://blog.77jp.net/mod_rpaf-install-apache-2-4

visualize the simple changes here: https://gist.github.com/teriyakisan/2716030

mod-remoteip is actually not as robust as mod-rpaf (yet)

There are improved copies of mod-rpaf around github too, like here https://github.com/y-ken/mod_rpaf/ which has https state support and removes some of the legacy support

Comment: Ah, good to know!